# Insert links in Word 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ms-office

I'm trying to add a link to a document in Word 2011 on my MacBook Pro, but the instructions for inserting hyperlinks are not working for me. **How can I insert a link into a Word document?**

---

Editor's Note: This question looked a lot different before and so I might have the wrong question here. -owlswipe

Comment: This is very unclear in its current form. Can you edit the question to clarify what instructions you're talking about, and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Fixed. It's a silly question still, but I've made it clear now.

Answer (score 1):

From the support article: [Create, edit, or remove a hyperlink](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-or-remove-a-hyperlink-68968ad1-a64d-4149-b814-59050e3a9c60).

> **Create a hyperlink to a Web page**
>
> 1. Select the text or object that you want to make into a hyperlink.
> 2. On the Insert menu, click Hyperlink.
> 3. In the Link to box, enter the Web address.
>
> NOTE: To link to a specific location on a Web page, click the Web Page
>   tab, and then under Anchor, follow the instructions.